# render view based on user request url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, request

I would like to render a specific view based on the users request url. Specifically, I want users who are signed in and who request signup_url to see one view, then a user who is signed in to see another view.
I tried using the following condition but i can't seem to get it to work

```
<% if signed_in? && request.url == signup_path %>
<%= render 'welcome_view' %>
<% elsif signed_in? %>
<%= render 'user_view' %>
<% else %>
<%= render 'welcome_view' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine, make sure you have the partials with the required names and in the right place. Be sure to check this [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) to learn more how rails handle views and partials.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are telling rails to look for an "url" but you supply a path. You just need to write this:

```
<% if signed_in? && request.path == signup_path %>
```